# loop javascript function?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Can anyone please tell me how i can add an infinite loop or a constant repeat on this piece of `JavaScript` I have?

```
<script>
$(".modcontentnewestmore").hide();
$('.morebutton').click(function () {
    if ($('.modcontentnewestmore').is(":hidden")) {
         $(".modcontentnewest").fadeTo(500, 0);
         $('.modcontentnewestmore').fadeTo(0, 500);

    } else {

        $('.modcontentnewestmore').fadeTo(500, 0);
              $('.modcontentnewest').fadeTo(0, 500);

    }
  });

</script>
```

Comment: Which part do you want to have repeat constantly?

Comment: Just make a for loop with `true` as the condition, although I'm not sure why you need this.

Comment: your question is very vague. what exactly are you trying to do?

Comment: What have you tried? What documentation did you read? Any research _at all_?

Comment: @Asad: Actually, no, that's wrong.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit Why is that wrong?

Comment: @Asad: Try it and find out. These are jQuery effects, and they take time to complete. You can't just shove a loop around them and expect the effects to queue properly; the results will be either quite bizarre or not visible. Plus, you'll have locked the script into a synchronous block and nothing else will be able to run... including, possibly, the entire rest of the browser GUI.

Comment: @LightnessRacesinOrbit That information is not present in the question, and you are extrapolating here. I was assuming he wanted to keep adding click handlers in an infinite loop, which is why I was puzzled.

Comment: @Asad: Huh? That _code_ is present in the question! Right there! Read it! Why on earth would anyone want to add click handlers in an infinite loop, when presented with the alternative that is the OP wants the effects to run infinitey?

Comment: Just asking a question on how to create an infinite loop seems strange, as most developers seem to figure out how to do that all on their own.

Comment: Possible duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9319573/how-to-repeat-loop-jquery-fadein-fadeout-fadein

Answer (score 1):

I think what you *should* use here is setInterval. Otherwise your loop will block any other javascript you'd want to run.

[JavaScript Timing Events](http://www.w3schools.com/js/js_timing.asp)

Comment: I think you should use jQuery's event and actions stack as designed.

Comment: Well that's all fine, but I don't know how much good it does to point out that the info is inaccurate if you don't say what's wrong with it. I'd really appreciate an explanation.  If you are saying to use the fadeTo method's callback parameter, it might be helpful to say so.

Answer (score 1):

```
<script>
  function doSomething{
  $(".modcontentnewestmore").hide();
  $('.morebutton').click(function () {
      if ($('.modcontentnewestmore').is(":hidden")) {
           $(".modcontentnewest").fadeTo(500, 0);
           $('.modcontentnewestmore').fadeTo(0, 500);

      } else {

          $('.modcontentnewestmore').fadeTo(500, 0);
                $('.modcontentnewest').fadeTo(0, 500);

      }
    });
  }
  setInterval(doSomething, 30); //it will loop the function doSomething every 30 ms
</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to keep replaying some JavaScript, rather than looping use an interval or timer.

```
var interval = window.setInterval(function() {
    console.log('hi');
}, 1000);
```

Answer (score 0):

Infinite loop? just use  following code.

```
while(true) {
   //do something here
}
```