# html javascript fade in and out picture loop

Tags: javascript, html, css

How can I fade in and out an image on a loop?
I want the image to fade in and out all the time until the user put the mouse hover the image, that's when I want the image to be shown, and when the mouse leaves the image- the fading will continue.

How can I do it with html/css/javascript/jquery?

Comment: By writing html/css/javascript/jquery.

Comment: Why reinvent the wheel, when many jquery Slideshow plugins exists?

Comment: I guess you can use CSS3 `animation-play-state: paused`

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/9319573/how-to-repeat-loop-jquery-fadein-fadeout-fadein

Comment: Where are not going to write the whole thing for you, but we suggests you at least try a few plugins for yourself and if you are stuck, maybe post what you tried and we might be able to help you more

Comment: This isn't a place for you to ask for code. This is a place to help solve problems with your code.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/87CNP/2/) explaining how to achieve that ;)

### html

```
<div id="your_flipping_img" class="animate"></div>
```

### CSS

```
#your_flipping_img{
    background-color:red;
    width:150px;
    height:150px;
}

.animate{
    -webkit-animation: flicking 2s; /* Chrome, Safari, Opera */
    -webkit-animation-iteration-count: infinite;
    animation: flicking 2s infinity;
    animation-iteration-count: infinite;
}

@-webkit-keyframes flicking {
  0%   {opacity:1}
  25%  {opacity:0}
  50%  {opacity:1}
  75%  {opacity:0}
  100% {opacity:1}
}

/* Standard syntax */
@keyframes flicking {
  0%   {opacity:1}
  25%  {opacity:0}
  50%  {opacity:1}
  75%  {opacity:0}
  100% {opacity:1}
}
```

### JS

```
$('#your_flipping_img').bind('mouseover', function(){
   $('#your_flipping_img').removeClass('animate');
})

$('#your_flipping_img').bind('mouseout', function(){
    $('#your_flipping_img').addClass('animate');
})
```

Comment: Please accept the solution if it help you out :) !

Comment: it did, but now I see that it doesn't work in IE.

Comment: Checked in google I found out that for the solution to work in IE it needs to be: 'animation: flicking 2s **infinite**;' instead of "infinity"

Answer (score 0):

A simple function for toggle fading :

```
var hover = false;
function myFunction()
{
    if(!!hover)return;
    $("#pic").fadeToggle();
    setTimeout(myFunction(), 600);
}
```

Prevent it if hover :

```
$("#pic").mouseenter(function()
{
    hover = true;
    $(this).fadeIn()
})
$("#pic").mouseleave(function()
{
    hover = false;
    myFunction();
})
```

As simple

Answer (score 0):

```
<script type="text/javascript">
    var timer;
    var opacityValue = 0; 
    function animate(event, object)
    {
        if(event == 'stop') {
            clearTimeout(timer);
        } else { 
            timer = setTimeout(function(){
                object.animate({
                    opacity:opacityValue
                });
                opacityValue = opacityValue ? 0 : 1;
                animate('start',object); 
            },1000);
        }
    }

    $('.imageClass').hover(function(){
        animate('stop',$(this));
    },function(){
        animate('start',$(this));
    });
    animate('start',$('.imageClass'));
</script>
```