# which one is best to repeat functions continiously either setInterval or callback function in jquery?

Tags: javascript, jquery

Actually in my project I have to reapeat few functions continiously,for that i have to use    setinterval or call back.which one is the best way to repeat function either call back or setInterval.lightAnim() same kind of functions i have more than 8.If i use setInterval what will be happened and if use callback what will be happened with respect to browser.which way one is best.

```
1st way:Using setInterval

   <script>
        lightAnim();

        setInterval(lightAnim,5000);

         function lightAnim() {
            $(".bulb1").fadeIn(1000, function() {
              $(".bulb2").fadeIn(1000, function() {
               $(".bulb3").fadeIn(1000, function() {
                  $(".bulb4").fadeIn(1000, function() {
                    $(".bulb5").fadeIn(1000, function() {
                        $(".bulb6").fadeIn(1000);
                    })
                });
              });
           });
         })
       }
       </script>

2nd way:On complete i am calling again


  <script>

   lightAnim();

     function lightAnim() {
     $(".bulb1").fadeIn(1000, function() {
        $(".bulb2").fadeIn(1000, function() {
            $(".bulb3").fadeIn(1000, function() {
                $(".bulb4").fadeIn(1000, function() {
                    $(".bulb5").fadeIn(1000, function() {
                        $(".bulb6").fadeIn(1000);
                        lightAnim();
                    })
                });
            });
        });
    })
}
  </script>
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/9319573

Comment: Here is a nice article about a workaround for setInterval. http://www.thecodeship.com/web-development/alternative-to-javascript-evil-setinterval/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The callback is definitely the better choice.

You don't need to sum the delays manually, and don't need to maintain it when updating the code. It's much more error-prone, as your code demonstrates: six one-second delays are not 5000 milliseconds. Your first snippet would animate the first and sixth bulb simultaneously.

Also, when you are animating a single element the animations would get chained onto jQuery's animation queue. If the timers deviate (and `setInterval` is known to drift over longer periods), then you could easily build up a very long queue (animations are scheduled faster than they are executed) which is not good for performance.

Comment: can i have more callback function for various functions like more than 10 functions ?

Comment: Sure. Just give them different names. Or even create them programmatically (but watch out for [closures in loops](http://stackoverflow.com/q/750486/1048572))

Comment: If i use 10 callback continuously ,in IE7 and IE8 Browser will get hang ?

Comment: That's unusual (but nothing I wouldn't expect from IE)